# Error indexing method 'QueueTrigger' Could not load type 'Azure.Core.SyncAsyncEventHandler

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, appinsights, queuetrigger

I have an azure functions queue trigger. It's working fine locally but not when deployed. In Application Insights I could see the below error message & the queue trigger won't get invoked because of this exception. I had a .netcore 3.1 app with azure functions v3. Even I upgraded it to .net6.0 & azure functions v4. Also, I tried upgrading, downgrading & installing some packages still it didn't resolve the issue.

[image: Error message]

How to fix System.TypeLoadException - Error indexing method 'NameOfQueueTrigger'. Could not load type Azure.Core.SyncAsyncEventHandler from assembly 'Azure.Core'?

Comment: Images Looks Good but along with that post your error message in the form of Text in Stack Overflow forum otherwise it would be difficult to grab the similar questions & answers for the people facing similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

***Microsoft removed the .NET 3.1 Support on Azure Portal Function App Deployment:***

[image]

Created the .NET 3.1 Azure Function App in Local Environment (VS Code) with Queue Trigger - Tested Locally:

[image]

When deploying V3 Project to V4 Azure Portal Function App, got the below warning and deployed successfully after clicking the option “deploy anyway”:

[image]

**Testing in Azure Portal**:

[image]

---

I’ve migrated the Queue Trigger Function Project from .NET 3.1 to 6 and Azure Functions core tools version 3 to 4 with the below changes:

[image]

**.csproj file code**:

```c
<Project  Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
<!-- <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion> -->
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference  Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage"  Version="4.0.5"  />
<!-- <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.1.1" /> -->
<PackageReference  Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions"  Version="4.1.1"  />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<None  Update="host.json">
<CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
<None  Update="local.settings.json">
<CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
<CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</None>
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

It asks to restore the missing dependencies after changing the versions in the `.csproj` file and click **Restore** them:

[image]

**Result**:
[image]

> Error indexing method ‘NameOfQueueTrigger’. Could not load type Azure.Core.SyncAsyncEventHandler from assembly ‘Azure.Core’

**For this error, check the following Steps:**

1. Check the Connection String defined in `local.settings.json` and in the Function Code are same and pointing to the correct storage account and Correct Queue name:

[image]

2. Refer to the MS Q&A 503163 given by @MayankBargali-MSFT on regarding the similar issue.